# Reason behind curved hockey stick?

Tags: equipment, trivia, history, ice-hockey, field-hockey

What is the reason behind curved hockey sticks?

I would like to know about it's history, reason of curve, benefits and science.

[image: Hockey Stick]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sticks are curved to better adapt to the type of shot before and during the hit.

The curvature in fact depends on the type of handle and the single-player (the bat is considered an extension of the arm).

You can find those kind of curve:

```
• Heel Open, Small
• Mid Round, Small
• Mid Round, Big
• Mid Round, Open
• Heel Open, Big
```

Furthermore to reduce the impact on the surface (specially on ice).

Historically there were an high evolution on material: from wood, aluminum, glass fiber, up to more recent materials: kevlar, graphite, titanium